# entry must be roll rate entry type?

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

while sending marketDataRequest, fix Server responded me with error message.

`entry must be roll rate entry type`

I do not understand why i'm getting s error. Here is my code.

```
MarketDataRequest mkrReq = new MarketDataRequest(new MDReqID(
                "Mkar-12345"), new SubscriptionRequestType(
                SubscriptionRequestType.SNAPSHOT_PLUS_UPDATES),
                new MarketDepth(0));

        NoMDEntryTypes group1 = new NoMDEntryTypes();
        group1.set(new MDEntryType(MDEntryType.BID));
        mkrReq.addGroup(group1);
        group1.set(new MDEntryType(MDEntryType.OFFER));
        mkrReq.addGroup(group1);
        MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSym symGroup = new MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSym();
        symGroup.set(new Symbol("EUR/USD"));

        mkrReq.addGroup(group1);
        mkrReq.addGroup(symGroup);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a counterparty-specific error, not a FIX or QuickFIX one.  Only someone familiar with your counterparty can answer this question.

Simply put, you are sending a message that is technically and syntactically correct, but is not what your counterparty wants to see.  Obviously, they want those MDEntries to be of a specific type and format, and your message doesn't conform.

You will have to check your counterparty's documentation to determine exactly what that means (or ask them directly).